# Adding nebular to project

Tags: html, css, angular

I am following along with a tutorial to build a basic tic-tac-toe game in angular as an introduction to the framework, but I am seemingly unable to run any angular CLI commands apart from version, which for some reason works, outside of the NX console extension.

The command I am trying to run is

```
ng add @nebular/theme
```

And it throws this error.

> This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a
> workspace.

I have verified that I am working in the project which is the noughts folder, with the following structure

\noughts

```
26/09/2023  17:42    <DIR>          .
26/09/2023  17:42    <DIR>          ..
26/09/2023  14:19    <DIR>          .angular
26/09/2023  14:16               274 .editorconfig
26/09/2023  14:16               548 .gitignore
26/09/2023  14:16    <DIR>          .vscode
26/09/2023  17:42    <DIR>          dist
26/09/2023  14:19    <DIR>          node_modules
26/09/2023  14:19               832 nx.json
26/09/2023  14:19           707,529 package-lock.json
26/09/2023  14:19             1,266 package.json
26/09/2023  14:19             2,469 project.json
26/09/2023  14:16             1,061 README.md
26/09/2023  14:16    <DIR>          src
26/09/2023  14:16               263 tsconfig.app.json
26/09/2023  15:08               905 tsconfig.json
26/09/2023  14:16               273 tsconfig.spec.json
              10 File(s)        715,420 bytes
```